# Is using strings this way inefficient?

Tags: c++

I am a newbee to c++ and am running into problems with my teacher using strings in my code. Though it is clear to me that I have to stop doing that in her class, I am curious as to why it is wrong. In this program the five strings I assigned were going to be reused no less than 4 to 5 times, therefore I put the text into strings. I was told to stop doing it as it is inefficient. Why? In c++ are textual strings supposed to be typed out as opposed to being stored into strings, and if so why? Below is some of the program, please tell me why it is bad.

```
 string Bry = "berries";
 string Veg = "vegetables";
 string Flr = "flowers";
 string  AllStr;
 float Tmp1, Precip;
 int Tmp, FlrW, VegW, BryW, x, Selct;   
 bool Cont = true;
 AllStr = Flr + ", " +  Bry + ", " + "and " + Veg;
```

Comment: Well, what reason did he/she give you? When somebody tells me I'm doing something wrong without explaining why, I usually just ignore the troll. A smart person will always explain or at least hint.

Comment: You don't have a good teacher, IMO.

Comment: C style strings can be less efficient than `std::string` - for example `strcat`. Because C strings don't know their lengths, that needs a scan of the first string (to find the null terminator) that isn't needed to concatenate std::string instances. Besides, std::string is much safer - particular WRT buffer-overflow style security issues - and generally easier to use, and there's this thing called premature optimisation.

Comment: @Steve314 that's a good point, which somewhat colors my answer (and those of some others), but doing std::string for that reason would also be an optimization that could be premature. For a first pass, the heuristic of: "most readable code that doesn't obviously waste performance" is what I go with.  The loss in assigning std::strings for literals that will only ever be used as r-values is obvious, the potential offsetting gain by avoiding repeated length calculations would probably require measurement before addressing.

Comment: @kylben - true enough - I only said "*generally* easier to use", and even that was based on an assumption I had in mind because I've written some very string-heavy code.

Comment: @Steve314, easier to use I can't argue with, (though to me std::string just doesn't "feel" right, but that's a personal style thing).  I do some fairly string-heavy code as well, but we have our own string class and formatters optimized for the way we use them, so I'm rusty on the day-to-day tradeoffs between std::string and native strings anyway. Security is an important consideration though.

Answer (score 9):

Answering whether using strings is inefficient is really something that very much depends on *how you're using them*.

First off, I would argue that you *should* be using C++ strings as a default - only going to raw C strings if you actually measure and find C++ strings to be too slow. The advantages (primarily for security) are just too great - it's all too easy to screw up buffer management with raw C strings. So I would disagree with your teacher that this is *overly* inefficient.

That said, it's important to understand the performance implications of using C++ strings. Since they are always dynamically allocated, you may end up spending a lot of time copying and reallocating buffers. **This is usually not a problem**; usually there are other things which take up much more time. However, if you're doing this right in the middle of a loop that's critical to your program's performance, you may need to find another method.

In short, premature optimization is usually a bad idea. Write code that is *obviously correct*, even if it takes ever-so-slightly longer to run. But be aware of the costs and trade-offs you're making at the same time; that way, if it turns out that C++ strings are *actually* slowing your program down a lot, you'll know what to change to fix that.

Comment: "They are always dynamically allocated" is not required by the standard, and many implementations will use the so called "small string optimisation", in which short strings are stored entirely in the memory of the string. Furthermore, C++ strings are often _more_ efficient than C strings, because they know their length in O(1). (Of course, C strings can carry length along with them too, but this is often not done.)

Comment: @Mankarse, indeed. But a lot of implementations _don't_ do the small string optimization, so if you're thinking about how efficient strings might or might not be, it's best to assume the worst case.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's fairly inefficient, for following reasons:

- When you construct a `std::string` object, it has to allocate a storage space for the string content (which may or may not be a separate dynamic memory allocation, depending on whether *small-string optimization* is in effect) and copy the literal string that is parameter of the constructor. For example, when you say: `string Bry = "berries"` it allocates a separate memory block (potentially from the dynamic memory), then copies "berries" to that block.

  - So you potentially have an extra dynamic memory allocation (costing time),
  - have to perform the copy (costing more time),
  - and end-up with 2 copies of the same string (costing space).
- Using `std::string::operator+` produces a new string that is the result of concatenation. So when you write several `+` operators in a row, you have several temporary concatenation results and a lot of unnecessary copying.

For your example, I recommend:

- Using string literals unless you actually need the functionality only available in `std::string`.
- Using `std::stringstream` to concatenate several strings together.

Normally, code readability is preferred over micro-optimizations of this sort, but luckily you can have both performance and readability in this case.

Comment: Most `std::string` implementations use copy-on-write; passing around copies of a const string is very cheap. The `operator+` argument is valid, but probably not at this level - concatenating five strings of a dozen characters each is not going to be a bottleneck either way, unless you're doing it in a tight loop.

Comment: @tdammers There were problems with copy-on-write even as far back as the SGI STL days (http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/string_discussion.html), let alone in the brave new multi-threaded world (http://www.gotw.ca/publications/optimizations.htm). As a consequence, I wouldn't count on "most implementations" implementing copy-on-write - e.g. my Visual C++ 2010 doesn't. But, even if it did, this is not relevant for constructing `std::string` from literal (it would be for constructing `std::string` from `std::string`, but this is not what OP does).

Comment: @tdammers As for `+`, please see my sentence about "micro-optimizations".

Answer (score 3):

Your teacher is both right and wrong.  S/he's right that building up strings from substrings at runtime is less CPU-efficient than simply providing the fully pre-built string in the code to start with -- but s/he's wrong in thinking that efficiency is necessarily an important factor to worry about in this case.

In a lot of cases, efficiency simply doesn't matter.  At all.  For example, if your code above is only going to be executed rarely (e.g. no more than once per second), then it's going to be literally impossible to measure any difference between the "most efficient version" and your not-so-efficient version.  Given that, it's quite justifiable to decide that other factors (such as code readability and maintainability) are more important than maximizing efficiency.

Of course, if your program is going to be reconstructing these strings thousands or millions of times per second, then making sure your code is maximally efficient, even at the expense of readability/maintainability, is a good tradeoff to make.  But I doubt that is the case here.

Comment: tl;dr = "Yes, it's inefficient.  So don't do that inside a tight loop where efficiency matters."

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is almost perfect - try and declare everything only once. But if it is not used more than once - dont wast you fingers typing it :-) ie a 10 line program

The only change I would suggest is to make the strings const to help the compiler optimize you program.

If you instructor still disagrees - get a new instructor.

Answer (score 1):

it is inefficient.  doing that last line right would be 4-5 times faster.

at the very least you should use +=

+= means that you would avoid creating new strings with the + operator.

The instructor knows that when you do a string = string + string C++ creates a new string that is immediately destroyed.

Comment: Note that this is only true in C++03; in C++11, with move semantics, temporary strings are not inefficient.

Comment: +1 for mentioning +=, but it's still premature optimisation if you make your code less readable to do it (don't ask for an example - it's in principle, not necessarily a real issue), and +1 for ildjarns comment too. There's still some extra new/delete overhead (you need two instances before one can be concatenated into the other), but C-style strings *may* need to live in dynamically allocated buffers anyway, and it's only rarely (if ever) a major issue anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Efficiency is probably not is good argument to not use string in school assignments but yes, if I am a teacher and the topic is not about some very high level applications, I don't want my students using string.

The real reason is string hides the low level memory management. A student coming out of college should have the basic memory management skill. Though nowadays in working environment, programmers don't deal with the memory management in most of the time but there are always situations where you need to understand what's happening under the hood to be able to reason the problem you are encountering.

Answer (score 0):

With the context given, it looks like you should just be able to declare AllString as a const or string literal without all the substrings and addition. Assuming there's more to it, declaring them as literal `string` objects allocates memory at runtime. (And, not that there is any practical impact here, but you should be aware that stl container objects sometimes allocate a default minimum of space that is larger than the number of things initially in it, as part of its optimizations in anticipation of later modifying operations.  I'm not sure if std::string does so on an declare/assign or not.) If you are only ever going to use them as literals, declaring them as a `const char*` or in a `#define` is easier on both memory and runtime performance, and you can still use them as r-values in `string` operations. If you are using them other ways in code you are not showing us, then its up to whether they need to ever be changed or manipulated as to whether they need to be `string`s or not.

If you are trying to learn coding, inefficiencies that don't matter in practice are still things you should be aware of and avoid if unnecessary. In production code, there are sometimes reasons to do something like this, but if it is not for any good reason, it's just sloppy. She's right to point it out, but what she should be doing is using that as a starting point for a conversation about the various tradeoffs involved - memory, speed, readability, maintainability, etc.  If she's a teacher, she should be looking for "teaching moments" like this rather than just an opportunity to scold.

Answer (score -1):

you can use string.append() ;
its better than + or +=

Comment: In what way is `append` better than `+=`? They do exactly the same thing.